# Prediction using forecasting techniques

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have trying to get predictions for insured population.[image: Time Series]

However, I don't know how to deal with the last period where the time series decreases. The number of insured people have decreased because some external causes, but I think that is logical that this period of decreasing lasts around 1 year more. And the the insured population should increase.

The problem is that if I use the general method to predict (ARIMA models) the prediction also decrease.

Someone have ideas to deal with it?